# jquery selected link activate but different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to activate selected link with jquery. But my links are grouped with css classes in different divs.

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="button-group">
        <a href="#" id="manu1">clients</a>
        <a href="#" id="menu2">supplier</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group">
        <a href="#" id="menu3">supplier</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery is like this.

```
$('div.menu-container').on('click','.button-group > a', function(){
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
})
```

I want to change selected link to **active** css class and others not. But my ***button-group*** is separating a tags. So two **a** link is appearing as active.

working app [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/kqexesrz/) is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the `active` class only for `siblings` element. Simply remove the active class for all anchor element like below. Update your script like below.

```
 $('div.menu-container').on('click','.button-group > a', function(){
 $('.button-group > a').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 })
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqexesrz/1/)

### EDIT:

According to your new requirement `if I click the second time to active link, it should be deactive`, update your jquery like below.

```
  $('div.menu-container').on('click','.button-group > a', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {
       $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    }
    else
    {
       $('.button-group > a').removeClass('active'); 
       $(this).addClass('active'); 
    }
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqexesrz/7/)

Comment: One click is activating link. Can you do if I click the second time to active link, it should be deactive?

Answer (score 1):

you need to go further upwards to reach them, try this:

```
$('div.menu-container').on('click','.button-group > a', function(){
  $(this).closest('.menu-container').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : remove `active` class from all anchor links present under `.menu-container` and then apply 'active' class to current clicked element.

```
$('div.menu-container').on('click','.button-group > a', function(){
      $('div.menu-container').find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kqexesrz/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:::

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[id ^= 'menu']").on('click',function(){
        $("a[id ^= 'menu']").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active')
    })


})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kqexesrz/4/)

Answer (score 1):

please see solution,

```
$('div.menu-container').on('click','.button-group > a', function(){
    $('div.menu-container').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```